# How to send emails with delayed delivery in Outlook from R?

Tags: r, outlook, delay, rdcomclient

Using the RDCOMClient package in R, I am sending a series of automated emails from R. The emails need to be sent at a specific date and time, but **I cannot figure out what elements in the `outMail` object to manipulate to send emails with delayed delivery**.

Here's a simple example of what I am doing:

```
library(data.table)
library(RDCOMClient)

# table of emails, names and send times (stt)
test_emails = data.table( First.Name = c("Joe", "Brit", "Anton"), 
                       email = c("Joe@fakeemail.com", 
                                 "Brit@fakeemail.com", 
                                 "Anton@fakeemail.com" ), 
                       stt = structure(c(1602270000, 1603270000, 1602470000), 
                                       class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""))


# access Outook
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")

# loop over table of names/emails
for(i in 1:test_emails[,.N]){
  
  #standard setup:
  outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
  outMail$GetInspector()
  signature = outMail[["HTMLBody"]]
  

  outMail[["To"]] = test_emails[i, email]
  outMail[["subject"]] = "Subject line"
  
 # example body that prints the time and date of when the email is sent
  outMail[["HTMLBody"]] =
    paste0("<p>Hi ", test_emails[i, First.Name], ",</p>",
           
           "<p>As discussed please find attached the detailed test instructions (PDF) and data set (CSV file)",
           "You received this email at ", 
           
           gsub('^0', '', format(econ_test[i, stt], '%I:%M %p')), ' on ',
           format(econ_test[i, stt], '%A, %B %d'), "</p>",
           
           '<p>',  signature, '</p>')

  # sends right now. How to delay this?
  outMail$Send()

}
```

I've tried looking through the MailModule object list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailmodule), but I can't find anything to use - and I'm not sure how to inspect the `outMail` object created above (e.g., `str()` doesn't work on this kind of object).

Thanks.

*** Exact Solution Based on Accepted Answer ***

```
# Convert the POSIXct integers to MS's time units
gmt_diff <- 4 # EDT

defer_time <-  as.numeric( as.Date( test_emails[i, stt]) ) + # convert to R's date values
               (as.numeric(test_emails[i, stt]) - gmt_diff*3600) %% 86400/ 86400 -  # convert the POSIXct time to fraction of a day
              as.numeric(as.Date("1899-12-30")) # adjust for differences in origin

# Update the DeferredDeliveryTime MailItem

outMail[['DeferredDeliveryTime']] = defer_time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `MailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime` property - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deferreddeliverytime

You don't need the MailModule object. Take a look at the live Outlook objects with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click the Item button on the OutlookSpy ribbon.

Comment: Thanks. This got me most of the way there - I can access and change the date/time value with `outMail[['DeferredDeliveryTime']]` but I don't understand this numeric value. It tells me its a "COMDate" object equal to 949998. But this does align with any time/date values I can find for MS apps (i.e., origin is 1899-12-30 putting today at about  44,113). Do you know what the unit of measure is for this variable and its origin?

Comment: Correction - the date/time variable is the standard one with days as units, origin on Dec 30, 1899 and time as fraction of a day. Realized i wasn't adjusting for the differences in bases when I used OutlookSpy to inspect the deferred dates (which held back 70 years and day, the difference between R and Outlook's base).

Answer (score 0):

since afaik Outlook needs to be running (ie online and connected) for you to achieve delayed delivery so therefore your computer also being powered up and running - why not time your R script accordingly with eg [taskscheduleR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/readme/README.html)